# How does "Get introduced" work on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I want to connect with a 2nd connection (Steve) through my 1st connection friend (John).

At my friend's name, I clicked "Get introduced".

Now it gets confusing:
It shows a line with my friend's name (John) and a text box to the right.
Below that it reads: "John, can you introduce me to Steve."

Should I type something to the right of John's name?
What will Steve actually see?

Answer (score 1):

If you want type some customise message you can, otherwise you can send it as pre-populated message. Its up to you how you want ask to John.

Steve will see the same message what you have sent to John if John forward it to Steve. Otherwise Steve will get John's message.

**Note**: You won't become 1st- degree connections unless one of you sends an invitation to connect and the request is accepted.

You can see Help Center: [Requesting an Introduction](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1959/~/requesting-an-introduction).